# How to make working continuous if - else statements in batch?

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, continuous, timetable

Is there an easier and more logical way to make continuous if - else statements in batch than the one that I am using nowadays. I'm very new to programming etc. and first I tried to make a code like this:

```
if %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
  if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
  ) else (
  if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
  ) else (
    if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
  )
) else (
Exit
)
```

Now the idea is that if time isn't over 8 it simply closes the program. But if it is over 8 then it goes and checks if time is less than 9 -> open subject1, less than 10 -> subject2 etc. But the code didn't work on the second *else* so I started to use this mainly because it works:

```
if %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
goto :check1
) else (
  Exit
)
:check1 (
  if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
  ) else (
    goto :check2
  )
)
:check2 (
  if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
  ) else (
    goto :check3
  )
)
:check3 (
  if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
  )
)
```

The second way works but it looks bad and is hard to read even to me. Is there a more simple way to do this?
The reason why I made this code is because my laptop is kinda slow to boot (SSHD hybrid drive instead of SSD) so I compensate the lost time by automatically run on boot (done) and connecting to wifi (also done) and opening the needed softwares and websites.

Answer (score 2):

#### Your first variant: nested `if`/`else` blocks

There are two closing parentheses missing in your code (7 × `(`, 5 × `)`).

This is your code with a little different indention:

```cmd
if %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
    if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
    ) else (
        if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
            start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
        ) else (
            if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
                start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
            )
        ) else (
            exit
        )
```

What you are trying to accomplish is probably this:

```cmd
if %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
    if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
    ) else (
        if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
            start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
        ) else (
            if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
                start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
            )
        )
    )
) else (
    exit
)
```

You could also write it like this:

```cmd
if %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
    if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
    ) else if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
    ) else if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
        start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
    )
) else (
    exit
)
```

---

#### Your second variant: flat `if`/`else` blocks

Also your alternative variant could be simpler; furthermore, labels should not be followed by `(`:

```cmd
if not %time:~0,2% geq 8 (
    exit
)
if %time:~0,2% leq 9 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject1.bat"
    goto :cont
)
if %time:~0,2% leq 10 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject2.bat"
    goto :cont
)
if %time:~0,2% leq 11 (
    start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\subject3.bat"
    goto :cont
)
:cont
```

---

#### Additional issues

1. Consider to use `exit /B` instead of `exit` as the former just quites the batch file while the latter terminates the underlying command prompt instance.
2. `start` (without the `/WAIT` option) does not wait until the run batch file has been finished; consider to use the `call` command instead.
3. The `%time%` variable may contain padding zeros, for instance, `08:30`, so `%time:~0,2%` expands to `08` rather than <kbd>SPACE</kbd>`8`; numbers with leading zeros are treated as octal ones, so the comparisons may fail; in order to avoid such trouble, you could do the following before your `if`/`else` blocks and use variable `%hour%` instead of `%time:~0,2%` for them:

   ```cmd
   set "hour=%time:~0,2%" & rem // (extract hour)
   set "hour=1%hour: =0%" & rem // (prepend `1`, replace leading <kbd>SPACE</kbd> by `0`)
   set /A "hour%%=100"    & rem // (remove leading `1`, avoid leading `0` finally)

   echo Hour value to be used further: %hour%
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The Batch code below answer your question: *"Is there a more simple way to do this?"*

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the "subject" array with batch files for each hour
set "subject[9]=subject1.bat"
set "subject[10]=subject2.bat"
set "subject[11]=subject3.bat"

rem Get the array element corresponding to current hour
set /A hour=1%time:~0,2%-100
set "file=!subject[%hour%]!"

if defined file start "" "C:\users\me\desktop\%file%"
```

For a further explanation of this solution you must understand what an *array* is, so I suggest you to read [this introduction](https://www.teamten.com/lawrence/programming/intro/intro11.html) first, then the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure) and finally [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990) on array management in Batch files.